# remove specific duplicate rows based on median

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, median

I currently have a data frame that looks like this:

```
        result 1    result 2    result 3    median 
item 1    8             7           6         7 
item 5    1             2           3         2 
item 1    6             5           4         5
item 5    3             4           5         4
```

I want to remove the duplicates based on the median, where I want to keep the duplicate entry with the higher median. 
Problem with this is that the rownames (item 1, etc) are not their own columns, so it's not accessible with $ operations.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could also be done with `top_n`, `df %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  top_n(1, median)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `order` decreasing and remove the duplicates, i.e.

```
df <- df[order(df$median, decreasing = TRUE),]
df[!duplicated(df$row),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>     row result1 result2 result3 median
> 1 item1       8       7       6      7
> 4 item5       3       4       5      4
> ```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but  the "row" column is actually just the rownames (it's not its own column) - how do I tackle this? Thanks for your help. Seems like a real easy fix.

Comment: nevermind, just added another column and took care of it. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'row' and then `filter` the rows having the `max` value for 'median'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(row) %>% 
   filter(median == max(median))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups: row [2]
#   row    result1 result2 result3 median
#   <chr>    <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>
#1 item 1       8       7       6      7
#2 item 5       3       4       5      4
```

If there are ties for max value of 'median' and we want the first row that matches, then use `which.max` with `slice`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    slice(which.max(median))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with **data.table**

```
library("data.table")
D <- fread(
"item   result1    result2    result3    median
item1    8             7           6         7
item5    1             2           3         2
item1    6             5           4         5
item5    3             4           5         4")
D[, maxmed:=max(median), by=item][median==maxmed]
```